# How to check if an object is present in a JSON file using R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, object

I'm trying to check if "confirmed" exists, if yes, I'll add it to my csv file, otherwise I want 0 to be added instead.
`df` is my data frame and `json` is where I've extracted my data.

This is my snippet:

```
i = 1
for (value in json$TT$dates){
  new_row <- c('TT', names(json$TT$dates)[i],if("confirmed"%in%value$delta) value$delta$confirmed else "0",value$delta7$confirmed,value$total$confirmed)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you specify what's the problem? And maybe provide us with dummy data to see what's wrong? As far as I am concerned, I'd rather use `ifelse()` instead of a if-else-clause, but I see no problem? If your problem is that you constantly overwrite `new_row`: create a vector before the loop (`new_row_all <- c()`) and add the new row in the loop (`new_row_all <- rbind(new_row_all, new_row)`)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.